# Model for survival data with an additional response

Tags: modeling, survival

I have a dataset looking like:

```
> dat
  time censoring  x
1   20         0 NA
2   10         0 NA
3   60         0 NA
4   80         0 NA
5  100         1  5
6   10         0 NA
7  100         1  6
```

(Of course the real dataset is bigger). The "time" column is the time-to-death of the individuals. For those indivduals who are still alive, we also have another response variable "x". This variable "x" is not a time-to-event, this is a quantitative variable like an indicator of the severity of a disease.

My question is: what statistical model could we use for such a dataset ? I want to jointly model all the columns of the dataset. Moreover I have in fact such a dataset for two groups of individuals, and the goal is to compare the two groups.

Comment: Have you considered competing risks?

Comment: @ocram, x is not a time-to-event, I don't see how are competing risks appropriate here

Comment: They are not if x is not a survival time, but nothing indicates the nature of x in your question...

Comment: Just to clarify - your question is how to model the joint distribution of two outcome variables where one of them is censored? Are there any other predictors?

Comment: There's no predictors (except the group). I want to model the joint distribution of the three variables (time, censoring, w). It suffices to model (time, x), because the censoring is independent, it is not a problem.

Comment: My answer that I removed was intended to address the question of model survival as a function of time and covariates.  I did not realize that she wanted to model the joint outcomes of survival and severity of disease.  But in this context maybe modeling survival as a function of disease severity would be more appropriate?

Comment: If you just had missing data on $x$, I would think you could stratify, but I gather $x$ is perfectly confounded with the censoring indicator. I think that makes the problem intractable.

Comment: Why don't you know the severity of the disease when there is censoring (i.e. no event has occurred)? Do you only know that the subject had the disease after they die?

Comment: @MichaelChernick this is the opposite. The time-to-event x is the time to death, and the censored individuals are those who are not dead at the end of the study.

Comment: @StephaneLaurent I know that the event is time of death and that the censored individuals are the ones that don't have the event.  But the covariate x is something like severity of the disease and yet you only list a score for it with the individuals that died.  My question was why you list it NA for those that do not die?  It seems that as ocram mentioned it is always missing for the censored individuals.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I repeat: x is NA for those who die (censoring=0), not for those who do not die (censoring =1)

Comment: @Stephane Oh Then why don't you know the severity of the disease for those that die?

Comment: I don't know. These data are recorded by some biologists (individuals are mices, nut human beings). But perhaps it is possible to ask them the x value for the dead mices.

Comment: @gung I don't see the intractability problem: x is not confounded with the censoring indicator, we could be interested in the distribution of x given T>C (ie censoring=1).

Comment: I think the question must not be clear. Like others, I was understanding $time$ `c(10, 20, 60, ...)` to be the *time-to-death*, and $x$ to be the *disease severity*. Thus, $x$ seems perfectly confounded w/ the censoring indicator. But based on your comments to @MichaelChernick, maybe that's not true. Are you saying that $time$ is severity & $x$ is time-to-death??

Comment: @gung you have well understand the dataset. It is true that x is observed only if the censoring occurs, but I don't agree to say it is confounded with the censoring: the censoring is only 0 or 1, and x is more.